# PHP MySQLI Object-Oriented with Wildcard

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, wildcard

I'm converting to Mysqli object-oriented (or trying to).  I have various category pages.  I'd like to use a parameter placeholder `'?'` in the include and then call up the right category on the category page.
This is as far as I've gotten.  How do I indicate the category on my page?  All works fine if I indicate `WHERE category = apples`.

I have this include at top of a category page

```
<?php require_once 'maincats_mysqli.php' ?>
```

which is below:

```
<?php 
$db = new mysqli('host', 'userName', '', 'dbName');
if ($db->connect_error) {
    $error = $db->connect_error;
} else { 
$sql = "SELECT pageName, gImage, prodName, prodPrice 
FROM tableName 
WHERE category = '?' 

ORDER BY dtList DESC";

$stmt->bind_param('s', ['$category']);

$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($db->error) {
    $error = $db->error;
    }
}
function getItem($result) {
return $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
?>
```

Below is part of one category page.  How do I indicate which category? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php 
if (isset($error)) {
echo "<p>$error</p>";
    }
?>

<?php 
while ($item = getItem($result)) { 
?>

<a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $item['pageName']; ?>">
<img src="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $item['gImage'];     ?>"</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $item['pageName']; ?>">
<?php echo $item['prodName']; ?></a>
<?php echo $item['prodPrice']; ?>

<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: 1) Remove single quotes from `... category = '?' ...`. 2) See this statement `$stmt->bind_param('s', ['$category']);`, it should be `$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);`. 3) You didn't **execute** your prepared statement. 4) RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Don't use single quotes on variables. Also see above notes ^. Also it is called a `placeholder`, not `wildcard`.

Comment: And oh, I almost missed, you didn't even **prepare** your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't declare `$stmt`.

Second, `?` is not a wildcard in this case, it's a parameter placeholder. You can use such placeholders when preparing the query, with `$mysqli->prepare($sql)`. See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
$sql = "SELECT pageName, gImage, prodName, prodPrice 
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE category = ?
    ORDER BY dtList DESC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Third, you encapsulate your variable in single quotes, so it's a string with a dollar and the name of your variable, not its content. And it must not be in an array:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);
```

Last: where does `$category` comes from? It's not defined in the script you show us. I guess it's from `$_GET`, so the previous line should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['category']);
```

Finally, you need to execute your statement, which contains the query:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT**:

To fetch results, you don't need that `getItem()` function. Just remove it.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Then you can loop over `$result` and fetch each row:

```
while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()):

// do you stuff

endwhile;
```

Note that I use here the [PHP control structure alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which is more clear in your case (`endwhile` is more explicit than just `}`)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `prepare()`.  Look at the first example in the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Note that you must not quote binded parameters.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time with this.  The information is already in my db table.  I just need to convert my ecommerce site from MySQL to MySQLi.  I used to have "Select" on each product page and category page to call up the info I needed.   Thought I could put Select in an include with MySQLi.  I've tried all suggestions above and nothing seems to be working.